# Hibernate или ORMLite для Android

Tags: android, sqlite, hibernate, orm, ormlite

Есть опыт работы с `Hibernate`. Сейчас же нужно написать приложение под андроид со встроенной СУБД естественно это `SQLite`. С `ORMLite` ни разу не работал, но увидел, что она популярна среди `Android` разработчиков, стоит ли её использовать? Или от использования `Hibernate` я ничего не теряю?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Я не слышал, чтобы где-то для Android разработки использовали `Hibernate`. Слишком большая библиотека, слишком много функционала, не нужного в мобильном приложении. Да и процесс инициализации не приспособлен к Android.

`ORMLite` будет хорошим решением. Многие крупные приложения его юзают и спокойно работают. И разобраться в нем легко.

Можно еще посмотреть в сторону `NoSQL`, например `Realm`. По скорости выигрывает.

Также, ради справедливости, уже на стадии `alpha` есть пакет `Room`, входящий в Android SDK, для более удобной работы с `SQLite`. Но лучше дождаться релиза.

Comment: Хороший ответ - молодец...

Comment: @Barmaley эмм... спасибо... наверное...